# Perfecting my MagicalRecord import

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Right, just cleaning up this question in a hope of finding an answer.

I've been following this blog to get my import working.

http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/

I managed to get the import working perfectly when the JSON was in the form...

```
[
    {
        Name: "John Smith",
        Id: 123,
        Company:
        {
            Name: "Apple",
            Id: 1
        }
    }
]
```

i.e. when the JSON contains the actual object.

The import will find the object and update the existing object rather than creating a new one.

However, some of the JSON I have has the format...

```
[
    {
        Name: "John Smith",
        Id: 123,
        CompanyID: 1
    }
]
```

and no matter what I do it creates duplicates.

Please can someone tell me what the Magical Record userinfo set up is to get this working.

Comment: I have tried out a sample code for your issue, please see if this is useful.

Comment: Why are using two different JSON model structures. If it's an optimization and you know company object already exists, you can use the same structure by keeping just that "Id" ?

Comment: The example is just for this question and not the same as my app. In my app there is no object called Person or Company. The two different structures are relating to entirely different objects in the actual app. I'm just trying to get both to work.

Comment: That is understandable without saying. But my point still holds. I was able to get this working by following one fixed format. But didn't work on trying both structures together.

Comment: How did you get the second way working? I haven't had any success with that at all? I've tried various setups but nothing has worked. The first way was easy.

Comment: For the second way,  I did the import in two steps. First I imported companies, saved them. After completion imported persons. Each person got correctly mapped to the respective company. I'm not very sure, I guess the second one only works if there is a object with the respective "primaryKey", and it will only try to link and not create .

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for your question I was able to successfully use the import feature of MagicalRecord, though I have been using for some time. I was able to get a solution to your issue.

I guess MagicalRecord makes it a convention to use personID for Person and companyID for Company. Since it's under our control its just a caveat to know. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Just after removing the underscore from properties of entities it didn't crash anymore.

I have fully tested below mentioned solution, please see the [demo project code](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestMagicalImport.zip) that I used. So feel free to raise questions.

```
Company
-------------
companyID (unique) //Removed underscore from the property
companyName
-------------
persons

Person
-------------
personID (unique) //Removed underscore from the property
firstName
lastName
-------------
company
```

For this format :

```
{
        Id: 1,
        FirstName: "John",
        LastName: "Smith"
        Company :
        {
            Id: 123
        }
    }
}
```

Following should be the provided in userInfo for the company relationship in person

`mappedKeyName : Company` (As used in the key of JSON)

`relatedByAttribute : companyID` (Unique property name in Company Entity)

For this model :

```
{
    Id: 1,
    FirstName: "John",
    LastName: "Smith"
    CompanyId: 123
}
```

`mappedKeyName : CompanyId` (As used in the key of JSON)

`relatedByAttribute : companyID` (Unique property name in Company Entity)

Comment: Thanks. I will test when back at my computer.

Comment: Just back on it now. Will let you know :D

Comment: @Fogmeister Sadly I couldn't get my solution working like yours. Still working on it.

Comment: Right, well I've got it to work with the object in the JSON but not with just the JSON. I keep getting an error with lookupKey. No idea where to go now.

Comment: @Fogmeister What is the error that you are getting? Can you discuss over it?